# How to use .replace() in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: replaceall

Am getting string like this for example

```
var names = "(Ajar,Sentinel,Manor,),(Dagwood,Steve,Guru,)";
```

I need output like this

> (Ajar,Sentinel,Manor),(Dagwood,Chateau,Guru)

When I use

```
names.replace(",)",")");
```

It is replacing only the first `",)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

for replacing all occurrence of a string, you should use regular expressions.
Example https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace

Or for temporary solution you can use

```
<p id="demo">My Output</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var names = "(Ajar,Sentinel,Manor,),(Dagwood,Steve,Guru,)";
    var res = names.replace(",)", ")").replace(",)", ")");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

For all Purpose Following code is working fine

```
function myFunction() {
 var names = "(Ajar,Sentinel,Manor,),(Dagwood,Steve,Guru,),(a,b,c,),(p,q,r,),(dfg,)";

    var res = names.replace(/\,\)/g,')');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```